# When is it appropriate to dynamically add attributes to a Python object?

Tags: python, class, rest, attributes

I'm creating a Python class as an API to objects managed remotely via REST.

The REST API includes a call that returns a list of dictionaries that define properties of the remote objects.  I'm in the process of writing code to dynamically add these properties as attributes of the corresponding Python objects (ie: when the class is instantiated, a REST query is made for a list of properties each of which is then added as an attribute on the instance.)

However, this brought back memories of PHP code I'd once glanced at that dynamically added attributes to objects and thinking "have you heard of dictionaries??"

Given my background is rooted in C/C++/Java this is a somewhat foreign idea to me, but is perhaps par for the course in Python (and PHP).  So, when is it appropriate to dynamically add attributes to an object rather than using a dictionary?

From what I've read in related material, it seems to me an API is a legitimate case.

Comment: Attributes are ostensibly stored in a dictionary called `__dict__`, anyways.

Comment: I believe that in Python, it's preferable to use dictionaries if the keys and values are homogenous. If you want to store an object hierarchy where every key points to a different type of value, use objects. That said, it would be nice if the objects had meaningful type names, especially if the API documentation uses them. (Like say Google's APIs do.)

Comment: @WaleedKhan It's not the storage abstraction that's my concern.  It's, I suppose, the programming practices, proper design, and avoiding misuse of language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disclaimer:  I know nothing about REST ...

That said, I would typically be a little hesitant to add attributes to an object willy-nilly for the following reasons:

- You might accidentally replace some data that you don't want to replace due to a namespace clash
- dictionaries are easier to inspect rather than having to go through `obj.__dict__` or `vars(obj)` or something similar.

There is precedence for adding attributes in the standard library however ... That's basically what `argparse` does to populate the returned `namespace`.  I think that perhaps it is worth asking the question:  "Will the user know which attributes are going to be added to the object?".  If the answer to this question is `yes`, and you're not worried about the afore mentioned namespace conflicts, then perhaps a simple object is appropriate, otherwise, I'd just use a dictionary.

Comment: The thing about "namespace" objects, as employed by `argparse` and others, is that they have no other attributes that could get replaced, and the attribute names are defined by the user in the first place (so introspection is a nonissue).

Comment: I ended up using a dictionary, which is just as well - it lets me track changes to all properties and send aggregate updates to the server.  Dynamically modifying object members got complicated quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In an example like that, I would be much more inclined to overload the dictionary methods -- `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `keys`, `values`, `items`, and whatever else may be applicable.

If you are formally defining classes to represent the data in Python, using [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) is not a bad option for readability.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you mean those dictionary methods as they apply to an object's __dict__ attribute?  I've considered descriptors, but that still leaves me with the question of how I deal with remotely retrieved parameters in my class.  Should I dynamically add properties with property()?

Comment: @Ben I think you understood the question the wrong way around. The OP doesn't want to fake a dictionary, he's just asking whether objects or dictionaries are more appropriate for his use case.